# Negative value converted to its positive counter part

Tags: c, if-statement

I am writing code for the game "craps".

I have an if statement. The variable that I am using in the if statement is returned from the is_win_or_loss_or_point(dice_sum). This function returns 1 if the sum is 7 or 11. It returns 0 if the sum is 2,3 or 12. If not one of those values it returns -1.

When I get a sum that causes it to return -1 (i.e. 6) point_value is assigned the value -1. point_value keeps its value of -1 when it hits the if (point_value == 0). But when it hits the else if (point_value == 1) it does something(in debugging it goes to positive 1) and then continues to go through the else if instead of continuing to the else statement.

```
int main()
{
balance=get_bank_balance();

while (balance > 0)
{
wager=get_wager_amount();

wager=check_wager_amount(wager,balance);
printf("Wager %.2lf\n",wager);

roll1=roll_dice();
roll2=roll_dice();

dice_sum=calculate_sum_dice(roll1,roll2);

point_value=is_win_loss_or_point(dice_sum);

if (point_value == 0)
{
    printf("You lose\n");
    new_balance=adjust_bank_balance(balance,wager,point_value);
    printf("Your current balance is %.2lf\n",new_balance);
}
else if (point_value = 1) // **point of interest**
{
    printf("You win\n");
    new_balance=adjust_bank_balance(balance,wager,point_value);
    printf("Your current balance is %.2lf\n",new_balance);
}
else 
{
    roll3=roll_dice();
    roll4=roll_dice();

    dice_sum2=calculate_sum_dice(roll3,roll4);

    point_loss=is_point_loss_or_neither(dice_sum2,dice_sum);

    new_balance=adjust_bank_balance(balance,wager,point_loss);

    printf("Your current balance is %.2lf\n",new_balance);
}
balance=new_balance;

}

}
```

Feel free to ask for additional info if I have missed something.

Comment: I'm not a c-expert, but shouldn't it be else if (point_value == 1)

Comment: = versus == , an old classic.

Answer (score 2):

`else if (point_value = 1)`is a hidden assignment. Turn your compiler warnings on.

Answer (score 1):

What is your prototype for is_win_loss_or_point ?

Also, maybe it's just that in your code you have one equal sign instead of two (you must write `else if (point_value == 1)`)

Answer (score 0):

An old classic. Instead of assignment

```
else if (point_value = 1) // = will assign
```

you wanted

```
else if (point_value == 1) // == will compare
```